# get list of Active Directory users with expiring password

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

Good day!

I know how to see the expiration date of a user's password in ActiveDirectory:

```vb
  Public Shared Function GetPasswordExpirationDate1(ByVal userId As String) As Date
        Dim forestGc As String = String.Format("GC://{0}", Forest.GetCurrentForest().Name)
        Dim searcher = New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry(forestGc)) With {
            .Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" & userId & ")"
        }
        Dim results = searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
        Return CDate(results.InvokeGet("PasswordExpirationDate"))
    End Function
```

question.
How to display a complete list of users whose password will expire after 10 days?
List get in DataGridView with fields: sAMAccountName and Password Expiration Date.

Answer (score 0):

I know since it looks like you are attempting to do this with vb.net you can just run the following PowerShell command and then pipe it's output to wherever you would like. You may have to create a PowerShell instance like the example I have below and then just run the code for doing it with C# in a Win forms application.

Create Powershell RunSpace:

```
private string RunScript(string script)
        {
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

Call powershell commmand into runspace (You can put this code on button click, or someting else):

```
_ = RunScript("Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq 
$False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select- 
Object -Property "sAMAccountName",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression= 
{[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}");
```

Then pipe the output to the data grid view using the "Out-String".